# Can't access secondary hard drive in other OS after hibernating

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, hibernate

I am running a dual boot setup: Windows 10 and Arch Linux.
I have windows OS installed on C: drive, and my data (documents, music, etc.) on D: drive.
In Arch Linux, I have fstab set to mount storage drive D: to a folder /home/storage in the file system.

When I hibernate Windows 10 (or have Fast Start enabled) and boot into Arch Linux, it fails to mount D: drive.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?
hiberfile.sys and pagefile.sys are both on drive C:. So, why is drive D: locked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the filesystem is shown as still-in-use by Windows (since it would still have been open) - thus thus the filesystem is showing up as unclean, and cleaning i**t could cause corruption when Windows next boots and tries to access a filesystem** which would, if modified by Linux, be in an unexpected state.

(Have a look at the Warning [here](https://answers.syr.edu/display/os/Enable+or+Disable+Hibernation+on+computers+running+Microsoft+Windows) - which states: After Hibernation it will be impossible to access the disk drive by booting from an external media like Linux Bootable CDs. Upon hibernation NTFS marks the hard drive "in use" status making it impossible for other OS to mount the drive.)